# Trigonometric equation $\tan x \tan 2x = \cot 2x \cot 3x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polynomials, problem-solving

> Find $\cos 8x$ if:
> $$\tan x \tan 2x = \cot 2x \cot 3x$$

We can verify quickly that $\tan 2x \to \infty$ and $\tan 3x \to \infty$ are not solutions of the trig equation, so the equation may be rewritten as:
$$\tan x \tan^2 2x \tan 3x = 1$$

Using expansion formulas, we may see that:
$$\tan 2x = \frac{2 \tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x}$$

And also:
$$\tan 3x = \frac{3 \tan x - \tan^3 x}{1 - 3 \tan^2 x}$$

By long calculations, I have obtained that:
$$\tan x \in \{-1 - \sqrt{2}, -1 + \sqrt{2}, 1 - \sqrt{2}, 1 + \sqrt{2}\}$$

However, I am not able to take those calculations further. I have learnt about Chebyshev polynomials, but using *WolframAlpha*, the expression is really hairy and not realy easy to cope with.

Is there a smarter trick to solve the question? If not, how should I simplify my calculations?

Comment: What is the tangent of $(22.5)^\circ$?

Comment: @user2661923 Apparently, $\tan 22.5^\circ= \sqrt{2} - 1$

Comment: Yes, that is the whole point.  The problem composer assumed that once you reached the end point of your analysis, as presented in your posting, you would recognize the values as the tangents of special angles.  Personally, I feel that this is unreasonable.  That is, while it is reasonable to expect the problem solver to recognize  trig function results around special angles like $30^\circ$ or $45^\circ$, I feel that $(22.5)^\circ$ is *pushing it*.

Comment: @user2661923 It depends on what you notice. As my answer shows, you don't even need to determine $\tan x$, let alone $x$: it suffices to identify a quadratic of which $\tan^2x$ is a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t:=\tan x$ and $T:=t^2\ge0$ (assuming $x\in\Bbb R$), so$$\frac{4T^2(3-T)}{(1-T)^2(1-3T)}=1\implies (T+1)(T^2-6T+1)=0\implies T^2-6T+1=0,$$and$$\cos4x=2\left(\frac{1-T}{1+T}\right)^2-1=\frac{T^2-6T+1}{(1+T)^2}=0\implies\cos8x=-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

> $\tan x \tan^2 2x \tan 3x = 1$

Using the product-to-sum [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) $\,\tan \theta \tan \varphi ={\frac {\cos(\theta -\varphi )-\cos(\theta +\varphi )}{\cos(\theta -\varphi )+\cos(\theta +\varphi )}}\,$:

$$1 = \tan^2 2x \cdot\frac{\cos 2x - \cos 4 x}{\cos 2 x + \cos 4 x}= \frac{1 - \cos^2 2x}{\cos^2 2x}\cdot\frac{\cos 2x - 2 \cos^2 2x+1}{\cos 2x+2\cos^2 2x - 1} \tag{1}$$

With $\,t = \cos 2x\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
t^2(2t^2+t-1)=(1-t^2)(-2t^2+t+1) \;\;&\iff\;\; 2 t^3 + 2 t^2 - t - 1 = 0
\\ &\iff\;\; (t+1)(2t^2-1) = 0
\\ &\iff\;\; t \in \left\{-1, \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right\}
\end{align}
$$

The root $\,t=-1\,$ must be excluded because the denominator in $\,(1)\,$ vanishes when $\,\cos 2x=-1\,$, which leaves $\,\cos 2x = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\tan$ and $\cot$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

$$\tan x \tan 2x = \cot 2x \cot 3x$$
$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}=\frac{\cos2x}{\sin2x}\frac{\cos3x}{\sin3x}$$
$$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\frac{\sin3x}{\cos3x}=\frac{\cos^2 2x}{\sin^2 2x}$$
$$\frac{\cos2x-\cos4x}{\cos2x+\cos4x}=\frac{1+\cos4x}{1-\cos4x}$$

Using cross multiplication and then simplifying we get,

$$\cos2x\cos4x+\cos4x=0$$
$$\cos4x(\cos2x+1)=0$$
$$\therefore ~~ \cos4x=0 ~~~ \text{or} ~~~ \cos2x=-1$$

$\cos2x=-1$ has the roots $x=n\pi\pm\frac\pi2, n\in\mathbb Z$, where $\tan x$ is undefined.

So we move on with $\cos4x=0$.

Thus, $$\cos8x=2\cos^24x-1=-1.$$

Comment: Nice. We might also justify Line 3's dividing by $\cos(3x)$ by verifying that none of its roots satisfy the original equation.

Comment: You can avoid this justification by performing cross multiplication in line 3 and then applying  trigonometric formulas for the products of sines and cosines.